# Structural directives, position tooltip

Tags: angular, tooltip, ng-template

I have created a structural directive that displays a tooltip based on what is inside an ng-template, when I hover over the text "see tooltip"
the tooltip is displayed correctly, but it is displayed in the top: 0px left: 0px position of the screen, I want it to be displayed just above the text "see tooltip", I have achieved the dimensions of the elementRef with the method "getBoundingClientRect()" but I do not know how to apply them in the tooltip. Any idea?

tooltip.directive.ts

```
import { Component, Input, HostListener,  Directive, ElementRef, 
TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef,  ContentChild, ComponentRef } from 
'@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[tooltipDirective]' })
export class TooltipDirective {
private tooltipId: string;
private dimensiones:{};
constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef,
          private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }

@Input() parametroPlantilla: TemplateRef<any>;
@ContentChild( "tooltipTemplate" ) private tooltipTemplateRef: TemplateRef 
 <Object>;
@HostListener('mouseenter')  onMouseEnter(): void {    
this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.tooltipTemplateRef);
this.dimensiones = this.elementRef.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();   
}
@HostListener('mouseleave')  onMouseLeave(): void {        
 if (this.viewContainerRef) {
    this.viewContainerRef.clear();
  }  
 }  
}
```

display.component.ts

```
...Some stuff

<div tooltipDirective>See tooltip!
  <ng-template #tooltipTemplate >      
      <div>   
          This is my tooltip!
      </div>      
  </ng-template>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would achieve it by moving generated tooltip inside host element so i would use only css rules to define position:

**tooltip.directive.ts**

```typescript
@Directive({ selector: '[tooltipDirective]' })
export class TooltipDirective {
  private tooltipId: string;

  constructor(
      private renderer: Renderer2,
      private elementRef: ElementRef,
      private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }

  @Input() parametroPlantilla: TemplateRef<any>;

  @ContentChild( "tooltipTemplate" ) private tooltipTemplateRef: TemplateRef<Object>;

  @HostListener('mouseenter')  onMouseEnter(): void {    
    const view = this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.tooltipTemplateRef);
    view.rootNodes.forEach(node => 
      this.renderer.appendChild(this.elementRef.nativeElement, node));
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave(): void {        
    if (this.viewContainerRef) {
      this.viewContainerRef.clear();
    }  
  }  
}
```

**html**

```html
<div tooltipDirective>See tooltip!
  <ng-template #tooltipTemplate>      
      <div class="tooltip">   <================ add class
          This is my tooltip!
      </div>      
  </ng-template>  
</div>
```

**css**

```html
[tooltipDirective] {
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}
```

**[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rgh6f4?file=styles.css)**

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked! but I'm not sure what this line of code does: 
      "view.rootNodes.forEach(node => 
      this.renderer.appendChild(this.elementRef.nativeElement, node)"  Could you explain it?

Comment: By default your `<div class="tooltip"` tag is placed next to the current element. This code inserts it inside `<div tooltopDirective`

Comment: Does anyone know how I can integrate an animation when the tooltip is displayed?

Comment: Which animation do you want to apply?

Comment: A animation like fadein and fadeout with transition, I don´t know how to apply it

Comment: Can we define tooltipTemplate inside the directive?

Comment: I would like to render an existing component

Comment: Yuruzi , so basically it adds it as a sibling due to createEmbedddedView , and then it's moved as a child ?(because same element cant be twice?)