# Dynamically position an element relative to another element with Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

If I have a grid row of several elements like this. Each element is a col-lg-3 with a `mouseenter` function. When mouseenter is triggered, we display the div with the class "popover", but given the div's position in the html, it always displays at the end of the row (the for loop). I want to display the div that has the class popover directly adjacent to the div hovered over. To do that, I need to get the position of the hovered over element and adjust the x,y coordinates, height, width, and other css properties of the div with the class "popover". Any thoughts on how this is done with Renderer2?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="card col-lg-3" *ngFor="let x of apples"
    (mouseenter)="displayPopover()">
    <div card-body">
      stuff here
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="popover" *ngIf="showPopover">
    <p>position me</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my typescript file I have a function like so:

```
displayPopover() {
     this.showPopover = true;
     // dynamically position the popover next to the div that was hovered over
}
```

Right now, the

Comment: this can help  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46872137/6885735

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Structural directives, position tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46867548/structural-directives-position-tooltip)

Answer (score 0):

Typically you will follow the concept of the parent having `position: relative` and child being `position: absolute` followed by `top bottom left right` properties. This will keep the element inside the parent, now to pull them out, you have to play with negative margin values.

Also, play with `z-index` in case the element goes behind some other element.

Now, for the Dynamic part, you don't need to do it dynamically, just have a pre-defined class and it should work. Still, want to do it dynamically? core javascript style functions work fine and can be used at proper component lifecycle event.

Also, more Angular way would be to have the classes rebuilt with properties and then just add class-based on flags wherever you want.

Hope this helps!